# How to add required attribute on contact form 7?

Tags: contact-form, contact-form-7

I want to add required attribute additionally on contact form.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C9SS.png)

```
<textarea name="your-message" required="required" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="your-message" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
```

How can I do in backend form?

```
[textarea* your-message id:your-message] <label for="your-message">Message</label>
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to add the html5 `required` attribute to a form tag in Contact Form 7. You can filter the form content and include it.  However, since the form submission is ajax, it won't really do anything unless you disable that also.

You can use the hook `wpcf7_form_elements` to filter the output and do a find/replace.

By looking for `name="your-field-name"` you specify the input / textarea tag vs the span that wraps the form tags.

```php
<?php
// Filter Form Elements
// Include in your child theme/theme's functions.php
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'dd_wpcf7_form_elements_replace' );
function dd_wpcf7_form_elements_replace( $content ) {
    // $name == Form Tag Name [textarea* your-message] 
    $name = 'name="your-message"';
    $str_pos = strpos( $content, $name );
    if (false !== $str_pos) {
        $content = substr_replace( $content, ' required="required" ', $str_pos, 0 );
    }
    return $content;
}
```

This above will output.

```
<textarea required="required" name="your-message" cols="40" rows="10" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-textarea" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: For anyone else that encountered trouble with this- since at least the `<select>` I wanted to work on also has a `data-name="fieldname"` attribute, this would break the markup, so I suggest adding a space here so the 7th line reads `$name = ' name="your-message"';` to avoid catching the data attribute.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

> `<label> Your Message (required) [text* your-message] </label>`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I don't have to add required attribute in label. I want inside the textarea.

Comment: Sorry - it's not easy to understand what do you want to achieve. Can you make it clear?

Comment: I have to implement required="required" attribute in textarea.

How can I do add in backend form in textarea section to get final result in html?

`[textarea* your-message id:your-message] `

Comment: Required is added by this sign, asterix - * - So your example actually answers the question. That is if I understand it right.

Comment: Agreed but I want to add it seperately in text. How can I do?

Comment: Sorry - no idea what you're trying to do. What does it mean 'separately in text'? Can you make it more obvious, maybe give an example, sketch or anything which would make it possible to understand the question....